# How to redirect on my service after logout using OpenAM?

Tags: redirect, logout, openam

Can I make logout account from openAM and redirect on my service?
I tried to send url like this http://myHost/OpenAM-12.0.0/UI/Logout?goto=myService, but OpenAM redirect me to SignIn-page. Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set property `iplanet-am-auth-valid-goto-domains` for your org.
You can do it with ssoadm tool

From [OpenAM Admin Guide](https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/11.0.0/admin-guide):

> Valid goto URL domains
>   List external domains to which clients can be redirected after authentication. 
>   This attribute requires valid DNS domains that reflect the set policy rules, 
>   such as (**need more reputation to post more than 2 links, see in admin-guide**).
>
> ssoadm attribute: *iplanet-am-auth-valid-goto-domains*